# rosdep is not installing pip dependencies

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, rosdep, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a package `perception` with the following in `package.xml`:

```
<exec_depend>open3d-pip</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>pyrealsense2-pip</exec_depend>
<exec_depend>python-opencv</exec_depend>
```

The first two are packages I've added myself here: https://github.com/luisrayas3/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml which is included in sources.list.d:

```
$ cat /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/10-luis.list
yaml https://github.com/luisrayas3/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
```

And in fact this does seem to not be the issue:

```
$ rosdep resolve pyrealsense2-pip
#pip
pyrealsense2
```

But `rosdep` does not try to install them:

```
$ rosdep install --simulate --reinstall perception
#[apt] Installation commands:
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-ros-base
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-image-common
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-image-transport-plugins
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-catkin
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-vision-opencv
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-perception-pcl
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-laser-pipeline
  sudo -H apt-get install ros-melodic-image-pipeline
```

On a whim I have tried to change the dependencies to `<depend>` without luck.

Additional info:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- ROS melodic

All help appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345312/rosdep-is-not-installing-pip-dependencies/) by [luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/51799/luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is already a ROS package named `perception` : http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=%5Eperception%24

The list of dependencies rosdep lists seem to match that package's dependencies: [https://github.com/ros/metapackages/blob/d2de28a9b2ce4878102bbb0258bb3cc437fa67ba/perception/package.xml#L18-L27'](https://github.com/ros/metapackages/blob/d2de28a9b2ce4878102bbb0258bb3cc437fa67ba/perception/package.xml#L18-L27%27)

Can you try to change the name of your package?

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/51799/luis/) on 2020-02-28**:
Thank you! That was indeed causing the problem.